# How to get enum values in activiti and what is return type of getType() of FormProperty in activiti?

Tags: grails, enums, activiti, bpmn

I want to get the values of the enum property.

In activiti 5.13 userguide,

the enumeration values are accessible with `formProperty.getType().getInformation("values")`

In activiti docs,return type of getType() is FormType. But in my code getType() return type is String. So i couldn't call FormType's getInformation() method.

When i am using `formProperty.getType().getInformation("values")`, i got the following error.

```
Cannot cast object 'enum' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.activiti.engine.form.FormType'.
```

How could i get the values of enum?

Comment: It looks strange. This code shoul work, may be you accidentally call formProperty.getType().getName() which returns "enum" string for EnumFormType

Comment: Hi Atmta, Thanks for your reply. Ya this code is correct. But i dont know why it is not working. for me, formProperty.getType() returns enum.

Comment: Can you try to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<userTask id="handleRequest" name="Handle vacation request" activiti:candidateGroups="management">
  <documentation>${employeeName} would like to take ${numberOfDays} day(s) of vacation (Motivation: ${vacationMotivation}).</documentation>
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:formProperty id="vacationApproved" name="Do you approve this vacation" type="enum" required="true">
      <activiti:value id="true" name="Approve"></activiti:value>
      <activiti:value id="false" name="Reject"></activiti:value>
    </activiti:formProperty>
    <activiti:formProperty id="managerMotivation" name="Motivation" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
  </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

Consider above user Task and You can do like this

```
//passing Task Id and Process definition Id

    def getFormForTask(taskId,pdId) {

        RepositoryService repositoryService =processEngine.getRepositoryService()

        // getting model 
        BpmnModel model = repositoryService.getBpmnModel(pdId);

        // getting list process from model including tasks
        List<Process> processes = model.getProcesses()

        List<FormProperty> taskFormPropertyList =[]

        for(Process proc : processes) {
            for(Object obj : proc.getFlowElements()) {
                // need form Property only for User Task
                if(obj instanceof UserTask) {
                    UserTask userTask = (UserTask)obj
                    if(userTask.getId() == taskId){
                     // getting list of Form Property from task that matches taskId
                        taskFormPropertyList = userTask.getFormProperties()
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    // loop through from Property
        taskFormPropertyList.each {
            // getFormValues() returns Property values for the form Property (like enum)
            def fvlist = it.getFormValues()
            fvlist.each {
               //  prints id, in this case true and false
                println it.getId()

              // prints name, in this case Approve and Reject
                println it.getName()
            }
        }

    }
```